# Не корректное отображение CalendarView на телефоне Xiaomi Redmi Note

Tags: android, datepicker, android-ui

На эмуляторе, на Samsung S5, Samsung J3 CalendarView отображается нормально а вот на Xiaomi Redmi Note отображается криво + приложение подвисает.
Собственно, если кто то сталкивался то куда копать?

[image: Это вот на Xiaomi]

[image: Это скрин какая система]

[image: Это с Samsung S5]

Первая картинка с китайского аппарата, вторая скрин экрана системы что стоит на китайском аппарате. Третий скрин - Samsung S5.

UPDATE: Разметка layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CalendarView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/scheduler_date_calendar"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 ## Заголовок ##android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

PS
Прошу прощения, CaldendarView а на DatePicker

Comment: Покажите разметку

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил в запрос

Comment: Попробуйте высоту тоже wrap_content сделать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб увы, не помогло

Comment: а если жёстко задать высоту? Например 200dp?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб увы нет. мне кажется здесь проблема лежит в том что он зависает... у меня увы нет прямого доступа к этому аппарату что бы подключить его к компьютеру и по логам посмотреть что там делается

Comment: Ну, без доступа и логов ничего сделать нельзя - в представленной вами информации ошибки не видать